# CAPL - How to use sysvar struct element with testWaitForSignalMatch

Tags: struct, capl, canoe

In my CANoe CAPL script I have defined a system variable `MyVariable` of my custom struct definition type with `Field1`, `Field2`, and `Field3` as struct members.
Access to the sysvar works like

```
@sysvar::Data::MyVariable.Field1 = 3;
```

In my test I want to check that to Field1 is written a specific value during I wait.
I tried the following:

```
testWaitForSignalMatch(sysvar::Data::MyVariable.Field1, 0, 1000); // Wait 1000ms for Field1 set to 0
```

Using this I get a compilation error:

```
Error     1002 at (200,100): parse error.
```

Does anybody know, how I have to use this correctly?

I am using CANoe version 10.0 (SP7). According to the Availability note in the help page this should be supported.

The help says:

> `long TestWaitForSignalMatch (sysvar aSysVar, int64 aCompareValue, dword aTimeout); // form 4`
> aSysVar
> System variable to be queried.
> May also be a specific element of a variable of type struct or generic array.

Using `testWaitForSignalMatch` with non-struct-elements works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use function `testWaitForSingalMatch` with struct members is:

```
testWaitForSignalMatch(sysvarMember::Data::MyVariable.Field1, 0, 1000); // Wait 1000ms for Field1 set to 0
```

You have to use `sysvarMember` instead of `sysvar`